# Django equivalent to "rake rails:freeze:gems" and "rake gems:unpack"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, freeze, self-contained

Is there and equivalent in Django to Rails' freezing and unpacking mechanism to a vendor directory so that an application becomes self-contained?

Comment: Did you try with setuptools? http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
pip bundle
```

intends to achieve the same.

http://pip.openplans.org/#bundles

Comment: Will that also bundle django itself, together with the application, and executable on the vhost with other django "neighbours" using other versions of django?