# get the modules locally for django project

Tags: python, django, python-module

Is there a way to import all the modules in the django project itself instead of setting up again and again in all the systems.
I would have used gem freeze or something like that in a rails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This way the python path of your django app only has stuff relevant to it. This also allows you to run several separate django / python apps on the same server without them bumping heads.

When you have a virtualenv with your django app running in it you need to generate a requirements file.

> pip freeze -E virtualenv_path > stable-req.txt

You can then use this file to generate a bundle.

> pip bundle mybundle.bundle -r stable-req.txt

This bundle can then be used to deploy with.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of a terminology confusion here: "modules" refers to individual `.py` files within a Python package. And importing is what you do within code, to bring modules into the current namespace.

I *think* what you're asking is how to **install** Python **packages** on deployment. The answer to that is, use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) with the `freeze` command, in conjunction with [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Acutally I just want to deploy a single app so I don't want to go through virtualenv at the moment. I just want to replicate the installed module from my development to the staging/production server.

Comment: Prabesh, even if you deploy a single "app" (you'd say "a site with one app"), it have dependencies, that you install. They are not "modules" but "packages". You use `pip` to install them. Also the best way for you to clarify dependencies is by using a bare virtualenv locally, in which you just install the strictly required packages: `virtualenv myenv --no-site-packages`, so once your app is working, `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will store the list, and `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install them again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
gem freeze
```

Try to use

```
pip bundle
```

I found this solution here: [Django equivalent to "rake rails:freeze:gems" and "rake gems:unpack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180370/django-equivalent-to-rake-railsfreezegems-and-rake-gemsunpack)

Comment: My apps name is sureaudio and I did pip bundle sureaudio.pybundle sureaudio . But I am getting an error message "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sureaudio" . Am I missing something here .

Comment: Well... I've not used bundles... ) Then try this: pip freeze > stable-req.txt

Comment: I did try that . It will list all the modules in stable-req.txt. Now how do I install those modules listed in stable-req.txt ?

Comment: You don't list your site in its own requirements.

Comment: You can install these modules with pip install -r stable-req.txt anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to import all modules?

It's a good practice to import only those modules, classes etc. which are needed...

Comment: Actually I am missing io module in my staging server which I have in my local system. I am using python 2.5.2 in the server and couldn't find a way to install io module there. So, I though I could push the io module from my development server to the production.